# Getting the values in between

Tags: ssrs-2008

In Report Builder 3.0 I have a string of comma separated values e.g. "Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4". I have used Split() to get the first and the last position but how do I get everything that is in between "Value1" and "Value4". Can I remove the first and last position in the array that the split function creates? The result i am looking for is "Value2, Value3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a couple of methods:

```
=Trim(Split(Fields!valueString.Value, ",")(1))
  & ", "
  & Trim(Split(Fields!valueString.Value, ",")(2))
```

Similar to what you're already doing, just concatenates the two values back together. `Trim` just helps avoid any issues with whitespace.

```
=Trim(Mid(Fields!valueString.Value
 , InStr(Fields!valueString.Value, ",") + 1
 , InStrRev(Fields!valueString.Value, ",") - InStr(Fields!valueString.Value, ",") - 1))
```

This just uses string manipulation based on comma positions. Again Trim is used to clean up whitespace.

Neither of these are necessarily perfect when your input string is an unexpected format, so depending on your data extra checks might be required, but for `Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4` both expressions return `Value2, Value3` as required.